# Unbiased Predictions for all Distinct Training Subsets

Tags: cnn, loss-function, gradient-descent, theory

Suppose I have a data set $\left(X_i \in \chi, y_i \in \zeta \right)$ where $X_i$ and $y_i$ correspond to instances and labels, and $\chi$ and $\zeta$ correspond to the space where $X_i$ and $y_i$ exist. For example, if I'm trying to use blood pressure ($X$) to predict resting heart rate ($y$), I might have the dataset $\left((X_i, y_i) = (120, 60), (130, 58), (118, 72), ... \right)$. Furthermore, using assumptions about the heart rate and blood pressure of people, I can say $\chi = [50, 90] $ and $\zeta = [95, 180]$ where "[]" is a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$. In otherwords, I know that nobody has a resting heart rate lower than 50 and higher than 90, and I also know nobody has a resting blood pressure lower than 95 and greater than 180.

Here's the question. Suppose I partition my set $\zeta$ into $k$ distinct subsets $\zeta_1, \zeta_2, ... \zeta_k$. These subsets, for example, might be $\zeta_1 = [95, 130], \zeta_2 = [130,160], \zeta_3 = [160,180]$ (i.e. different groups of people based on blood pressure: low, medium and high blood pressure). **Suppose for each subset of labels, I want my machine learning model to make unbiased predictions**. I should note that a model that makes unbiased predictions on $\zeta$ as a whole (trained with a regular RMSE loss function) can still make biased predictions on each $\zeta_i$ (it might overpredict the blood pressure of people with low blood pressure and underpredict the blood pressure of people with high blood pressure, for example). **What is the best loss function to use to prevent this from happening, and make unbiased predictions in each label region $\zeta_i$?**

1. I've tried training with the loss function $L = L_0 + \alpha \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{|\zeta_j|}\sum_{y_i \in \zeta_j} (\hat{y}_i - y_i)$ where $L_0$ is the MSE loss function and $\hat{y}$ are the predictions, and while this does a decent job, it can often lead to unstable training conditions. In addition, it requires using many instances in a single gradient descent step (note the summation over instances).

Comment: I think you may be missing some $j$ index in the loss formula, can you double-check it?

Comment: Fixed! Good catch!